# How to translate notification message with parameter using Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-translate

I am unable to translate the notification message when its come to parameters using **ngx-translate/core**

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
en.json :
   "message": {
        "Successfully removed account": "Successfully removed account"
        }
```

Above is the translation json

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService,
private userService : userService)

async deleteAccount(account) {
try {
  await this.userService.removeuserAccount(account.id);
  this.notificationService.sendSuccess(this.translate.instant(`message.Successfully removed account ${account.id}`));
} catch (err) {
  this.notificationService.sendError(this.translate.instant(`message.Unable to delete account: ${err.message}`));
    }
  }
```

Kindly help me to handle this issue

we need to fix similar to this issue in the link in components
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/pull/990

Comment: What is message.Successfully

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: particular notification is not getting translated. as it has variable when i remove the variable it get translate

Comment: Is message.Successfully just a string or a variable?

Comment: its fetch from json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Answer.
Translate it and Append to the Variable.

```
    constructor(private translate: TranslateService,
    private userService : userService)

    async deleteAccount(account) {
    try {
      await this.userService.removeuserAccount(account.id);
      var status = this.translate.instant('message.Successfully  removed account');
this.notificationService.sendSuccess(this.translate.instant(status + `${account.id}`));
    } catch (err) {
var statuserr = this.translate.instant(`message.Unable to delete account:');
      this.notificationService.sendError(this.translate.instant(statuserr +` ${err.message}`));
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

As the message is coming from JSON, you need to use

```
this.translate.instant(message['Successfully removed account'] + account.id)
```

**PREVIOUS ANSWER:**

If `message.Successfully` is also a component variable like an ENUM or something,

use `${message.Successfully} removed account ${account.id}` as an argument to the method within the backquotes (`)

If backquotes is not supported and `message.Successfully` is just a string, use

```
this.translate.instant("message.Successfully removed account " + account.id)
```

if `message.Successfully` is not a string and if it is a variable, then use

```
this.translate.instant(message.Successfully + "removed account " + account.id)
```

Comment: we need to fix similar to this issue in the link in components
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/pull/990

Comment: You could fix the issue?>

Comment: @Monisha, Please look at my updated answer and let me know if it helped you.

Comment: we tried earlier particular notification not getting translated

Comment: ngx-translate/core. use this.translate.instant method..actually this is working fine without parameter. Its not working with parameters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188469/discussion-between-monisha-and-dileepkumar-jami).